# Proof of the weak Goldbach Conjecture

Tags: nt.number-theory

What are the main ideas of Harald Helfgott's [proof](http://arxiv.org/abs/1305.2897) that all odd $n \geq 5$ is the sum of 3 primes?

Comment: I for one certainly believe the proof is correct. It was already known modulo a large finite computation; the new ideas are aimed (I believe) towards lowering that modulo-computation, to the point where it has been done already.

Comment: Didn't Vinogradov prove it for sufficiently large odd numbers in something like 1937? So, it seems reasonable to believe that deciding the question one way or the other would be a matter of time after that.

Comment: For the first question, I would simply read the introduction of Helfgott's paper.

Comment: I am not well placed to comment on details (and am sceptical regarding such questions in general) but in view of some other contributions I would like to say that since Vinogradov there were a number of contrib. towards getting the full conjecture, so if it is (and this seems likely) now fully settled this seems like quite an achievement. I have no time to write in detail but just a remark: only recently it was shown that all odd numbers (except minimal exceptions) are sum of 5 primes (Tao) improving on Ramaré (6 primes, for even). So now 3 (not 'only' 4) IMO is impressive.    

Comment: Your question seems suitable for a blog.  Since Terry Tao already has a blog discussion on this topic, I've voted to close. 

Comment: It would be nice to have the possibility to downvote (or upvote) the actions of closing some of the questions.

Comment: @Christi Stoica: if you disagree with a closure the best thing to do is to start  a thread on meta. (Link at the top; extra sign up necessary, but easy and instant. Sign-up, top right, then 'apply for membership' which is granted instantly.)

Comment: Geoff - the problem was that previously existing constants were larger than the number of subatomic particles in the universe multiplied by the number of microseconds since the Big Bang...

Comment: @H A Helfgott: I was intending to be supportive of you in the sense that given that the result was known to be true in all but a finite number (however ridiculously large) number of cases, there would seem to be no reason not to believe that the result had now been proved. Sorry if it sounded otherwise, that was not my intention at all.

Comment: Don't worry, Geoff.

Comment: It seems to me (an algebraic number theorist, mainly), that analytic number theory, which appeared to me at a little bit sleepy when
I was in grad school (at the ENS), is now experiencing an impressive blossom a little bit similar that the one that algebraic number theory experiences after Wiles' proof of Fermat. I mean, in the last ten years, the proof of the existence or arbitrary long sequence in
primes, of infinitely many bounded gaps between primes, of the weak Goldbach conjecture, and so many other beautiful things. It is very heartening,
as was Wiles' announcement.

Comment: @Joël: I disagree. I believe analytic number theory was a constantly busy subject throughout the 20th century, just think of the circle method, sieves, zero density results, automorphic forms and automorphic L-fuctions, and several really big heros in the subject, some of who are very much alive and still working. On the other hand, I do agree that the subject got more fashionable lately, perhaps because of the constantly growing number of connections to other subjects, and the recent fascinating easy-to-state but hard-to-prove developments.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think this blog post of Terry Tao, as well as the comments following it (including some from Helfgott) answer this question as completely as one could reasonably hope.

https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2012/05/20/heuristic-limitations-of-the-circle-method/

Comment: Note that the blog post was written a year ago.  It is still relevant, though (particularly the comments by Helfgott).

Comment: Does this also show every odd number $n > 5$ is of form $n=2p+q$ where $p$ and $q$ are some primes?

Comment: I would say Terry Tao's post is a good explanation of why proofs based on the circle method (such as mine) will not, in and of themselves, work out for the binary Goldbach problem. My comments give some idea of my strategy for the ternary problem (as of May 2012), but I think I've explained things better elsewhere.

Answer (score 14):

https://plus.google.com/114134834346472219368/posts/8qpSYNZFbzC

Comment: This link does not work anymore, can give alternative source?

Comment: The link in your answer is broken. Would it be possible that you replace it by an up-to-date link -- and also elaborate a bit more, such that this is not just a link-only answer?

Answer (score -7):

It needs to be *iterated* once again, that Vinogradov showed in 1937 that all large enough odd numbers are sum of three primes. The current contribution of Helfgott merely aims at bridging the gap between *large enough* and *all number*.

This is an interesting problem. However where-as Vinogradov's proof introduced the *fundamentally new* idea of bilinear forms, Helfgott contribution is on a much smaller scale. While it contributes to the particular sub-field of analytic number theory concerned with explicit estimates, it most likely does not contribute to the larger field, and instead uses idea that were around for a long time.

Comment: "It needs to be iterated once again,..." Why? And, you do not answer the question. 

Comment: But pooper is at least living up to his or her name! 

Comment: As in party-pooper, I suppose (for those who don't know the English expression: someone who acts in a way to dampen enthusiasm).  

Comment: Not to be an anti-pooper, but, actually, most of the ideas and improvements in my proof are qualitative rather than quantitative. I'm not an explicit person by training, and I have no doubt that careful specialists could improve on some of the constants within the proof by being more clever than I was.

One of several "morals" of the story (not really new, but more people should be aware of it) is the close relationship between bilinear forms, the circle method and the large sieve. Of course, Vinogradov was working before the development of the large sieve.

Comment: "It needs to be iterated once again" because most people who ask questions about Goldbach are not aware of Vinogradov's work. The second point I was trying to make is that I am of the impression that while very nice and striking, this work, will not have repercussions for analytic number theorists unconcerned with explicit estimates (something people unaware of the first point typically ignore). I would be surprised if Harald disagreed (in good faith) with me.

Comment: First, it was said (in some sense even twice!) before your answer and is mentioned very prominently in the paper itself (by line 8 or so). Second, if you are so little informed about the actual content of the paper as to not even being able to give any type of substantive information that might remotely qualify as an answer to the (first) question, it is really unclear to me why anybody should care about your impression. (If you could but did not this seems even worse.) 

Comment: I actually disagree (in good faith I think) with pooper: I do think analytic number theorists who don't care a fig about explicit constants would find several things in what I've done to be of interest. I just gave a talk highlighting the more conceptual bits. At any rate, I'll make the obvious point that not just Vinogradov but also Hardy and Littlewood deserve credit as initiators here.


Comment: Perhaps I travel in different circles than pooper, but the theorems of Vinogradov and Chen were among the first things I learned after hearing of the existence of the Goldbach problem.  Isn't it common, when introducing a famous open problem, to describe roughly how far we've come?

Comment: Er, yes. See section 1.2, "History", of majarcs.pdf, and section 1.2, "History", of minarcs.pdf, as well as the first and second paragraphs of each paper.