# Distribution of Goldbach's weak-conjecture's prime-triples

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, goldbach-type-problems

From Harald Helfgott's proof of [Goldbach's weak conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_weak_conjecture),<sup>1</sup>
we know that every odd number $> 7$ is the sum of three odd primes.
If $n$ is such an odd number, say that two sums that yield $n$
are distinct if they are distinct as sorted lists. So $n=13$ has
just two distinct sums, $(3,3,7)$ and $(3,5,5)$.

> ***Q1***. Are $9=3+3+3$ and $11 = 3+3+5$ the only two odd numbers $> 7$ that
>   have unique sums of three odd primes?

Call a sum of three odd primes as a *$3$-sum* for conciseness.
Here are the first few odd numbers and their $3$-sum lists:
$$
\left|
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & 3{-}sums & \#3{-}sums\\
\hline
9 & (3,3,3) & 1\\
11 & (3,3,5) & 1\\
13 & (3, 3, 7),\; (3, 5, 5) & 2\\
15 & (3, 5, 7),\; (5, 5, 5) & 2\\
17 & (3, 3, 11),\; (3, 7, 7),\; (5, 5, 7) & 3
\end{array}
\right|
$$

Here is a plot of the number of $3$-sums for odds up to about $1001$:

---

[image: Goldbachs_1000]

---

> ***Q2***. What explains the separation into two distinguishable series?

So for $n=975$, there are $701$ $3$-sums:

\begin{eqnarray}
&(3, 5, 967)\\
&(3, 19, 953)\\
&(3, 31, 941)\\
&\cdots\\
&(313, 313, 349)\\
&(313, 331, 331)
\end{eqnarray}

But for $n=977$, there are $1106$ $3$-sums. Here is a bit more data:
$$
\left|
\begin{array}{cc}
n & \#3{-}sums \\
\hline
 975 & 701 \\
 977 & 1106 \\
 979 & 1010 \\
 981 & 758 \\
 983 & 1113 \\
 985 & 977 \\
 987 & 756 \\
 989 & 1110 \\
 991 & 1037 \\
 993 & 791 \\
 995 & 1056 \\
 997 & 1096 \\
 999 & 770 \\
 1001 & 1095 \\
\end{array}
\right|
$$

---

<sup>1</sup>MO: [Proof of the weak Goldbach Conjecture](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/130545/proof-of-the-weak-goldbach-conjecture)
.

Comment: Did you think about mod 3 considerations?  Gerhard "Can You Finish The Thought?" Paseman, 2019.06.18.

Comment: Presumably Helfgott and Platt's computations determined that the answer to Q1 is "yes" among the first 10-to-the-umpteen integers, and Helfgott's explicit bounds for larger integers show that the answer to Q1 is "yes" for the rest.

Comment: Have you considered the integers 'many' 3-sums of which are of the form $(p, p, q)$ with $p\neq q$?

Comment: Are you familiar, Joseph, with "Goldbach's Comet"?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I did not know about Goldbach's comet. What a great name! Clearly my plot is a (monochromatic) version of the comet for triples rather than pairs. I appreciate learning of this---Thanks!